Is there a way to set node/pod status update frequency for KWOK running outside a cluster
I have a K8s cluster running on its own, and I added some nodes/pods with labels and annotations so kwok will take care of them. Kwok is its own process running on the same host independently. Everything works well at first.
However I’m simulating 6k nodes and 50k pods, thus at certain point, it seems the API server is overloaded and the whole cluster got degraded.
Is there a way to set node/pod status update frequency for kwok running outside a cluster? Per my understanding, Kwok will send heartbeats and status updates for nodes and pods to API server. How can I tune this frequency? If there is no direct solution, can you point to me where I can hard code it in the source code so I can build my own version
thank you very very much!

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

I don't think it might be the right answer, but correct me if wrong

To manage the status update frequency for nodes and pods in kwok, you can adjust the settings related to heartbeat and status updates.

You can follow the below points to construct your own version.

By getting the source code for kwok from its Github repository, you may try to attempt to clone the repository.

Also change the values for instance if there’s a ticker that sends   updates every second, you might change it to every five seconds.


After making these changes, rebuild and deploy it in your cluster.
For example if you find something like this ,
Ticker := time.newTicker ( 1 * time.second ) then you change it as below ,
Ticker := time.newTicker ( 5 * time.second )
For the performance tuning , try to implement batching of updates to reduce the number of API calls and if you are not using informers can help to reduce the load by caching the state and only sending updates whenever it is neccessary. Refer to the LinkedIn community page written by Mbong Ekwoge for more information on this.
Additionally you can also  check how to manage nodes and pods with KWOK for more details.

yeah I was looking at the source code but I can't locate a timer or somethng that is relevent

If you are unable to locate the timer in the source code,you can try using a code search tool or commands like grep to search for keywords related to heartbeat or status updates. For example,
grep -r “heartbeat”
grep -r “status”

Based on my code reading, there is no direct timer on node heartbeats or pod status update.
My understanding might be wrong, but here is what I got from code reading:
Kwok only allows user to configure a node lease duration. However, upon increasing lease (at frequency of lease duration / 4), it actively triggers Node and Pod Sync event. On the other side, Kwok also has a event listener, once it finds Create, Delete or Sync events on node or pod, it will send status update to control plane

I want to confirm this behavior
Thus I need more than a general guidance but very accurate answer about where this logic presents in the code
Still, thanks for answering my question anyway! appreciate it

Could you please tell me whether the issue has been fixed or not ? If not,I am happy to assist further.
